# Error message doesn't look right

Tags: discussion

When I was posting an comment to a question I got an *Server Connection Closed* error message, but reading the message it doesn't look right(grammatically) - (I'm not a native English speaker so I could be wrong).

[image: Error Screenshot]

Shouldn't the description be something like `The server requested to close the connection before the transaction was completed`

Comment: I suspect that isn't a message from Stack Overflow itself. Are you behind a proxy, or corporate firewall?

Comment: @StevenV no, there are no proxies or firevwalls. I'm in my home network...

Comment: It is clearly correct because everyone would think that "The server closed the connection." is correct.  It is that requested that makes it sound awkward but is a fine modifier of serer.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that the subject of that sentence is "The server requested" so, while perhaps a little awkward, it does seem to be correct.

subject = The server requested
verb = closed
object = the connection

Perhaps

> The requested server closed the connection before the transaction was completed.

or

> The server that was requested closed the connection before the transaction was completed.

or

> Oops! Something bad happened!

would be good alternatives.

That assumes, of course, that that's a message generated by Stack Exchange's software.

Comment: Okay, that last one is a bit tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read it like this in order to see that it is correct -

> The server requested {pause} closed the connection...

Comment: Given that, probably should change that to "The *requested* server...."

Comment: That pause only works if you read it like this guy and then put on sunglasses: http://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/csi-miami.jpg -- YEAAAAAAAOOOOOOOWWWWWWWW